# python replace two list data from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In python in one variable i am getting list like :

```
stop_address_type = ['1','2']
```

and in another variable i am getting like :

```
stop_facility_name = ['A','B']
```

Result : this is what i actually want

```
stop_address_type = ['1','2']
stop_facility_name = ['','B']
```

another situation like :

```
stop_address_type = ['2','1']
stop_facility_name = ['A','']
```

what i actually want is when i ll get the 1 value in stop_address_type variable i want to blank the same value of list stop_facility_name like :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the lists through a method like this:

```
stop_address_type = ['1', '2']
stop_facility_name = ['A', 'B']

def check_facility_name(address_typ_list, facility_name_list):
    for i, obj in enumerate(address_typ_list):
        if obj == '1':
            facility_name_list[i] = ""

print(stop_facility_name)
# ['A', 'B']

check_facility_name(stop_address_type, stop_facility_name)

print(stop_facility_name)
# ['', 'B']
```

This will give you the desired output no matter where the 1 occurs in the adress_type_list

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
stop_facility_name = [n if t != '1' else ''
                      for n, t in zip(stop_facility_name, stop_address_type)]
```

This works with any number of '1's in your `stop_address_type` list.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the index of '1' in stop_address_type using the `index()` method and then fill stop_facility_name with a blank:

```
i = stop_address_type.index('1')
stop_facility_name[i] = ''
print(stop_facility_name)
```

With `stop_address_type = ['1','2']` and `stop_facility_name = ['A','B']` you will get the following output:

```
['', 'B']
```

Please note that this will only work if there is only one occurrence of '1' in stop_address_type.

---

If you have more than one occurrence of '1' in stop_address_type, you could use list comprehension to get all the indices of the '1' occurrence and fill the corresponding values in stop_facility_name with a simple for loop:

```
stop_address_type = ['1','2','1']
stop_facility_name = ['A','B', 'C']
indices = [i for i in range(len(stop_address_type)) if stop_address_type[i] == '1']
for i in indices:
    stop_facility_name[i] = ''
print(stop_facility_name)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
['', 'B', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the first value in `stop_address_type` as an index into `stop_facility_name`, you can do it like this:

```
stop_facility_name[int(stop_address_type[0])] = ''
```